# How do I automatically translate my website into the user's language?

Tags: javascript, html, google-translate

I have a website in English, and recently some users reported that they do not know English, so I thought, maybe the site is not accessible to everyone, because some do not know English.

So my question is: is there any way for the website to automatically translate into the user's language?

I've been searching, it seems that Google has a translation API, is this what I need?

**EDIT**

I want to detect the user's browser language and translate the page into the user's browser language. We can obtain the language of the browser using `navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage` in JavaScript. Is there any way to integrate this with the Google API and then automatically translate without requiring user interaction?

I think it may be possible through control structures and methods, or by passing a variable as a parameter on the Googgle Translate website, am I right?
Please, I need help, I don't want the user to choose the language, I want to translate automatically, I want to recognize the language of the user's browser and automatically translate

Note: I use `<meta charset="UTF-8">`, does this affect anything?

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_google_translate.asp or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46966839/using-google-translate-code-to-auto-translate-webpage-onload ?

Answer (score 2):

Remember how you asked me how I can detect the user's language? Well I finally came up with a code for that. Code is below.

```js
let lang = window.navigator.languages ? window.navigator.languages[0] : null;
    lang = lang || window.navigator.language || window.navigator.browserLanguage || window.navigator.userLanguage;

let shortLang = lang;
if (shortLang.indexOf('-') !== -1)
    shortLang = shortLang.split('-')[0];

if (shortLang.indexOf('_') !== -1)
    shortLang = shortLang.split('_')[0];

console.log(lang, shortLang);
```

I hope this is what you are looking for!

Comment: Navigator in js is very useful to get user info.

Answer (score 1):

This answer might answer the question and the solution is from w3schools. What it basically does is that a dropdown will be created with different types of languages. Here is the code, tell me if it works.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<body>

<h1>My Web Page</h1>

<p>Hello everybody!</p>

<p>Translate this page:</p>

<div id="google_translate_element"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>

<p>You can translate the content of this page by selecting a language in the select box.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: try it out now in a different code editor.

Comment: Very good, it works. But is there no way to implement code and detect the language of the user's device and then translate it into the language of the user's device?

Comment: You might be able to achieve this with js. I'll post a solution when I get one:)

Comment: @coder9927 Suppose I use this. For a better user experience, would you recommend that I create a modal when loading the page asking the user to select the language, or place it somewhere on the page?

Comment: I reccomend somewhere else on the page because that's how you usually see it on websites which are professional.

Answer (score -1):

Is it ok, to make a request to google services on behalf of the user? Google will gleefully want to know what page the user is surfing, and will know by the automatic translation request. This will have to be encapsulated by an opt-in on site load.